# ¿Puedo agregar un elemento a un objeto JSON en php?

Tags: php, mysql, json, jsonobject, jsonarray

**Buenas comunidad**
Quisiera saber si puedo agregar un elemento a un elemento de tipo JSON en php, explico;
Tengo un resultado que me arroja un php en mi consulta a mysql obteniendo esto:[image: Datos arrojados por JSON]
Hasta aquí todo bien, pero ahora lo que quiero es que desde mi archivo php pueda meter el dato "Seleccionar" ya intente de muchas formas y nomas no arroja el resultado que espero

```
<?php
require("../conn/Conexion.php");
    $json=array();
    $select="Seleccionar";
        $conexion = mysqli_connect('localhost',$username,$password,$database);

        $SELECT_CLIENT="SELECT MARCA FROM MARCAS ORDER BY MARCA ASC";

        $resultado=mysqli_query($conexion,$SELECT_CLIENT) or die(mysqli_error($conexion));

        while($dato = mysqli_fetch_array($resultado)) {
            #$variable['titulojs']=$dato['campo_de_tabla']
            $jsArray["marca"]="Seleccionar";
            $jsArray["marca"]=utf8_decode($dato["MARCA"]);

            $json['marcas'][]=$jsArray;
        }
        mysqli_close($conexion);
        echo json_encode($json);?>
```

y no se que pueda estar mal, se que no deberia poner mi item de Selecionar ahí ya que lo que hace es recorrer todos los resultados de la base de datos, pero aun poniendolo afuera no consigo que se agregue . ¿como puedo hacer esto?

Comment: ¿Donde quieres agregar "Seleccionar"?, si puedes mostrar como esperas que este tu JSON ayudarías mucho

Comment: ¿Cómo tendría que quedar el JSON final, con una clave raíz que sea `seleccionar` o cómo? Pon un ejemplo pulsando en [edit]. Gracias. Y, ¿si tienes un cargo de conciencia de que eso no está bien, por qué lo haces entonces? Si explicas lo que estás haciendo, o para qué lo necesitas, quizá podemos sugerirte otras ideas que no te dejen con esa sensación de que algo no anda bien en tu código.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inicializa el arreglo con `Seleccionar`, a menos que quieras agregarlo por cada marca.

```
        $json['marcas'][] = array( 'marca' => 'Seleccionar' );
        while($dato = mysqli_fetch_array($resultado))
            $json['marcas'][] = array( 'marca' => utf8_decode($dato["MARCA"] );
```